# Multiple insert identity get

Tags: sql-server-2005

My query in Stored procedure looks like this.

```
insert into a(name) select name from b.
```

I want to get all the new identity value from a.
How can i do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

```
insert into a(name)
OUTPUT INSERTED.IDColumn  --this line for >1 row
select name from b.
```

The [OUTPUT Clause](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [OUTPUT Clause (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx)

Something like

```
DECLARE @a TABLE(
        ID INT IDENTITY (1,1),
        Name VARCHAR(250)
)

DECLARE @b TABLE(
        Name VARCHAR(250)
)
INSERT INTO @b SELECT 'a'
INSERT INTO @b SELECT 'b'
INSERT INTO @b SELECT 'c'
INSERT INTO @b SELECT 'd'

INSERT INTO @a(name) 
OUTPUT INSERTED.ID
SELECT name FROM @b
```